# How to inverse arrow head position in Jung tree?

Tags: java, jung

I am building a tree using Jung that must have the edge arrows inverted. That is, instead of having parent -> child, having child -> parent.

I cannot change the tree layout structure because I am using the corresponding methods for further analysis - I only need this feature for visual purposes.

I am using the jung library as a dependency in my Eclipse project and cannot edit the files provided directly. I have tried extending the BasicEdgeRenderer class (and also tried to create a modified copy of this class) to override the drawSimpleEdge() method and invert the vertices but this leads to countless of errors I can't seem to fix.

I have then thought about making the edges undirected and add the arrowhead manually at the desired point, but no success so far!

Any help as to how to achieve this would be appreciated!!

Edit: I've added the part of my code related to my graph display - the Tree has vertices of custom nodes of type Node and edges of type String.

```
Layout<Node, String> newLayout = new TreeLayout<Node, String>((Forest<Node, String>) G);
VisualizationViewer<Node,String> vViewer = new VisualizationViewer<Node,String>(newLayout);
vViewer.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(
        new Transformer<Node, String>(){
            public String transform(Node v){
                return v.getLabel();
            }
        });
vViewer.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR); 
vViewer.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(new EdgeShape.Line<Node,String>());
vViewer.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);
vViewer.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You might want to consider adding your latest code so we have a basis on which to help you.

Comment: For my own future reference: we (JUNG) should consider making it easier to create "uptrees", in which the edges are going the opposite direction, as you desired.  This is arguably a problem with the data model not being the one you want, not a problem with the visualization system, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the effect you want in one of the tree sample programs by doing the following:
I extended BasicEdgeRenderer and overrode drawSimpleEdge as follows:
first, around line 342 and 344, it fills then draws the edge arrow. 
g.fill(arrow) and g.draw(arrow).
Comment out those lines and you will not get the arrow that you don't want. Next, the code checks to see if this is an undirected graph:

```
if (graph.getEdgeType(e) == EdgeType.UNDIRECTED)
```

and if so, it draws the reverse arrow (the one you DO want). By commenting out the test to see if the graph/edge is undirected, it will draw the arrow you want.
Sorry the code is so messy in that class.

Comment: Thank you! -  I have managed to extend the class and override drawSimpleEdge() without any errors.. However, regardless of which changes I make, there is no difference on the graph... (it will not print anything on the console either) - could that be because this function is not actually called? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you do something like this to set the EdgeRenderer to the new one you wrote?            

vViewer.getRenderer().setEdgeRenderer(new MyBackwardsArrowEdgeRenderer());

Comment: Had to create a specific class for it and did exactly that - worked like a charm!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Joshua's answer is nice, but if you don't also change line #239 from:

```
AffineTransform xf = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x2, y2);
```

to:

```
AffineTransform xf = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x1, y1);
```

you will not see any arrows at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is another modification to `BasicEdgeRenderer.drawSimpleEdge()` that you could do that's a bit more hermetic.

Basically, the code always draws an arrow pointed towards the second endpoint of the node, and it draws another towards the first endpoint if the edge is undirected.

What you want is for it to always draw an arrow pointed towards the *first* node, so you can change this (lines [236-7](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/jung-2.1.1/jung-visualization/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/renderers/BasicEdgeRenderer.java#L236)):

```
graph.getEndpoints(e).getSecond()
```

into:

```
graph.getEndpoints(e).getFirst()
```

and this (lines [245-246](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/jung-2.1.1/jung-visualization/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/renderers/BasicEdgeRenderer.java#L245)):

```
getArrowTransform(rc, edgeShape, destVertexShape)
```

into:

```
getReverseArrowTransform(rc, edgeShape, destVertexShape)
```

(If you want the modified code to do the right thing for undirected edges also--you'd then change line [264](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/jung-2.1.1/jung-visualization/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/renderers/BasicEdgeRenderer.java#L264) so that it called `getArrowTransform()` instead, but for your purposes you probably don't care.)

You could even create a modified version of BasicEdgeRenderer that has an option for doing this reversal for you; the logic would be easy.  That may be overkill for you, though.

Tom's solution also works fine, the modification is just a bit more extensive.

Related question: [Q: How to change arrow position or remove it from an edge ? (JUNG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036280/q-how-to-change-arrow-position-or-remove-it-from-an-edge-jung/)